# Do I need an Airport Transit Visa? (Copenhagen to Exeter via London and Dublin)

Tags: visas, uk, transit, brexit, danish-citizens

I'm traveling to Exeter from Copenhagen via London (Southend) and Dublin (I have no idea why the airplane is landing in Ireland).

I am a Danish citizen with a Danish Passport and all.

Question is, do I need an Airport Transit Visa?

I am traveling on April 13th (March 29th = Brexit )

This is how I am traveling to Exeter:

Copenhagen -> London Southend Airport
(22.25 - 23.55 local time) Ryanair

London Southend Airport -> Dublin Airport
(06.55 - 08.10) Ryanair

Dublin Airport -> Exeter Airport
(09.55 - 11.05) flybe

PLEASE don't come @ me if it's obvious that I need an Airport Transit Visa

Last time I was in the UK, I was on my way to Egypt, so I needed a Visa for that.

OBS! In Dublin I'm changing Airlines, so have that in mind!

Comment: Exeter in the UK? If so, that’s a very strange routing! Is London Southend airport even open overnight? The train might be a better option once you arrive in the UK

Comment: I know right! But I have already paid for the tickets and all so I can't just take the train ... Ryanair and flybe will sue my ass.

Comment: Danish citizens or any other EU citizens will need a visa after brexit even in the event of no deal, immigration may take longer if there's no deal, if there's a transition period then it will be the same as it is now

Comment: @BritishSam so I just have to apply for a UK Visa on March 21st and I'll be good to go?

Comment: @OmarFadelAl-Ali no just travel with your Danish passport, if it's a no deal brexit Danish citizens will still have visa free travel to the UK for up to 6 months at a time. If there is a deal Danish citizens will be allowed to settle in the UK still till the transition period ends.

Comment: Just to finalise, you WILL NOT need a visa no matter what happens after 29th March, just travel with your Danish passport.

Comment: @BritishSam that sounds like an answer.

Comment: @phoog I can't find an official source from the government! I just know Danish citizens are not going to need a visa to come to the UK

Comment: Arrangements for visa-free travel to the EU for British citizens are currently deadlocked. See [Britons may need £52 visa to visit mainland Europe after Brexit](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2019/feb/20/britons-may-need-52-visa-to-visit-mainland-europe-after-brexit). If that does not get worked out before Brexit, the UK government may retaliate by requiring visas for EU citizens.

Comment: @Patricia Shanahan Jesus Christ ... I guess I have to wait until March 29th to get the final answers.

Comment: Incidentally, I really hope that common sense will somehow prevail. Visits to the EU for British citizens and visits to the UK for EU citizens should be visa-free by normal standards. It will be a mess, and totally overload the visa systems, if it does not get sorted out.

Comment: @BritishSam it's still an answer.

Answer (score 4):

**You are making life difficult for yourself.** Use another mode of transport.

I had friends who tried exactly this. Used to North America, where the default option going anywhere is to fly to the nearest airport, they tried to get to Exeter airport (from Toronto) and found that the routing was extremely convoluted. They asked my advice.

My advice was that everyone going to a small town in the UK flies into a major airport and then takes ground transport to get to their destination.

They found that getting to Exeter involved a flight to Heathrow and then two or even three more more flights. This is because Exeter is a small airport and so doesn't have direct connections to Heathrow (since Heathrow is an expensive airport to fly to). Exeter only connects to other small airports. hence the need for at least 2 more flights. You are seeing the same thing.

**Your best approach by far is to land at Southend and then take a train to Exeter.**

For example, if you were to land at Southend airport early on April 13th you could get no less than [five trains that got you to Exeter St Davids by midday.](http://ojp.nationalrail.co.uk/service/timesandfares/SIA/Exeter/130419/0430/dep). The cheapest is 25 pounds.

And of course doing this you don't need any visa other than the one you need to stay in Britain anyway (if any).

IN ANY CASE

As a Danish citizen you are allowed to enter Ireland without a visa, so you have no problem there. You also have the ability to enter the UK visa free under current rules. So your only problem will be if the UK rules change because of Brexit. While nobody can realistically predict the exact circumstances of brexit, it would seem to be extremely unlikely that the UK will suddenly bar EU citizens from travelling to the UK after mere weeks, even with  a no-deal Brexit. If they do, you will be in good company as tens of thousands of travellers will face the same issues.

Comment: I know ... but I am not landing early

Comment: Your timetable said you are landing at 23:55, so able to take an early train.

Comment: True. But can you answer me if I need an Airport Transit Visa if I don't take the train from London Southend?

Comment: EU citizens do not need any sort of transit visa for the UK right now. You are entitled to visa-free entry, which makes a transit visa entirely superfluous. After Brexit, the situation may change, but the most recent announcement is that EU citizens will be treated like Canadians and Americans: they do not need an advance visa and will be stamped in at their port of entry (here, London Southend).

Comment: AFAIK EU nationals can even continue using the ePassport gates post-Brexit.